# SymmetricDS Active-Active able to replicate client-master but failed to replicate master-client

Tags: symmetricds

I have problem replicating the Active-Active SymmetricDS. From the client server, I can insert, update and delete the record, and also it is replicated to the master without any problem.

But from the Master, any insert, update and delete that I had made were not replicated to the client.

The 2 servers that I have :

- Master with public ip
- client with only local ip

Here is the gt2_master.properties in master server :

```
db.connection.properties=
sync.url=http\://{cloudip}\:31415/sync/gt2_master
group.id=gt2
db.init.sql=
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.user=dbuser
db.password=dbpass
engine.name=gt2_master
external.id=1
db.validation.query=select 1
cluster.lock.enabled=false
registration.url=
db.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://{cloudip}:5432/gt2?protocolVersion\
=3&stringtype\=unspecified&socketTimeout\=300&tcpKeepAlive\=true

job.purge.period.time.ms=7200
job.routing.period.time.ms=1000
job.push.period.time.ms=1000
job.pull.period.time.ms=1000
auto.registration=true
initial.load.create.first=true
```

And here is my gt2_client.properties on client :

```
db.connection.properties=
sync.url=http\://192.168.100.203\:31415/sync/gt2_client
group.id=gt2
db.init.sql=
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.user=dbuser
db.password=dbpass
engine.name=gt2_client
external.id=2
db.validation.query=select 1
cluster.lock.enabled=false
registration.url=http\://{cloudip}\:31415/sync/gt2_master
db.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://192.168.100.203:5432/gt2?protocolVersion\
=3&stringtype\=unspecified&socketTimeout\=300&tcpKeepAlive\=true

job.routing.period.time.ms=1000
job.push.period.time.ms=1000
job.pull.period.time.ms=1000
auto.registration=true
```

bin/sym_service starts running without any error log. Then i run this command in master :

```
INSERT INTO sym_node_group_link (source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,data_event_action)
VALUES ('gt2','gt2','P');

INSERT INTO sym_trigger (trigger_id, source_schema_name, source_table_name, channel_id, sync_on_update, sync_on_insert, sync_on_delete, sync_on_update_condition, sync_on_insert_condition, sync_on_delete_condition, last_update_time, create_time)
VALUES ('public.all', 'public', '*', 'default', 1, 1, 1, '1=1', '1=1', '1=1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO sym_router (router_id,source_node_group_id,target_node_group_id,router_type,router_expression,sync_on_update,sync_on_insert,sync_on_delete,use_source_catalog_schema,create_time,last_update_by,last_update_time)
VALUES ('gt2_2_gt2', 'gt2', 'gt2', 'default', NULL, 1, 1, 1, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'console', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

INSERT INTO sym_trigger_router (trigger_id, router_id, enabled, initial_load_order, create_time, last_update_time)
VALUES ('public.all', 'gt2_2_gt2', 1, 10, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

All sym_* table and sym_ trigger were created. Finally i run this in master :

```
bin/symadmin open-registration --engine gt2_master gt2 gt2_client

bin/symadmin send-schema --engine gt2_master -n gt2_client
```

In client server there is no error in log but in the master server there is a warning error :

```
WARN [gt2_master] [PushService] [gt2_master-push-default-41] 
Could not communicate with gt2:2:2 at http://192.168.100.203:31415/sync/gt2_client 
because exception org.jumpmind.exception.
IoException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connect timed out
```

What is wrong with my configuration or postgresql command ?

Comment: can master server (let's call it server) can connect to client server (let's just call it client)? if client is within a private network the server might not be able to reach it. in that case the synchronization could be made unidirectional, i.e., changes on the client to be pushed to the server and the data changed on the server to be *pulled* bu the client

Comment: My client is within private network. So how to do push and pull from server ?

Comment: one symmetricDS engine can P -- push to another engine or it can W -- wait for another engine to pull the payload. I think the direction is defined in 'sym_channel'

Comment: Could you please give me the detail instruction ? I am quite new to Symmetricds

Comment: Go to the configuration table sym_channel and configure your channels for push and pull

Comment: i dont know how to do that. Could you please give me detail command i should run

Comment: You’ll need to learn some SQL to configure